# MySQL stability issues after attempting to backup WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

I was trying to create a backup of a WAMP directory so I could attempt to install a 32-bit version since I need a PHP library that required it for an assignment. I'm currently just a stand-in while my place of employment tries to find a replacement for the guy who vacated the position and set all this up, and it's a bit over my head and I'm lost in the procedure.

The MySQL process keeps crashing when I attempt to create a temporary table as part of a data conversion. Error log from startup to crash:

> 140620 10:32:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   140620 10:32:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 343041027227
>   140620 10:32:24  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
>   InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>   InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>   InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
>   InnoDB: buffer...
>   InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 343041027247
>   InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 43092, file name .\mysql-bin.000238
>   140620 10:32:27  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>   140620 10:32:28 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 343041027247
>   140620 10:32:28 InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 4 !!!
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 8 events
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
>   Version: '5.5.20-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   140620 10:32:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
>   140620 10:32:43 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table centralprocessing1/importscanning from
>   the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
>   table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
>   files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
>   of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
>   or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
>   doesn't support
>   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
>   how you can resolve the problem.
>   140620 10:32:43  InnoDB: Error: table `centralprocessing1`.`importholdover` does not 
>   exist
>   in the InnoDB internal
>   InnoDB: data dictionary though MySQL is trying to drop it.
>   InnoDB: Have you copied the .frm file of the table to the
>   InnoDB: MySQL database directory from another database?
>   InnoDB: Dump of the tablespace extent descriptor:  len 40; hex
>   0000000000000001000e0000252effffffff000000000004aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafeff; asc             > %.                          ;
>   InnoDB: Serious error! InnoDB is trying to free page 932476
>   InnoDB: though it is already marked as free in the tablespace!
>   InnoDB: The tablespace free space info is corrupt.
>   InnoDB: You may need to dump your InnoDB tables and recreate the whole
>   InnoDB: database!
>   140620 10:32:43  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 4408 in file fsp0fsp.c line 3265
>   InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>   InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>   InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
>   InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>   InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
>   InnoDB: Thread 5360 stopped in file os0sync.c line 781
>   InnoDB: Thread 6568 stopped in file os0sync.c line 474

Errors that show up in the console include 1146 (Table doesn't exist; the table it's   looking for is the temporary one i'm trying to make), 1051 (unknown table), 2013 (lost connection), and 2006 (Server is gone). When i try to step through the batch file, it crashes when I attempt to make the new table and I'm not sure what I can do about it

Comment: have you tried making sure that the `importholdover.frm` file is not in this databases folder? It seems to be saying I am trying to create your tem table but I already have a .frm with that name.

Comment: Turns out we were going to start moving away from that database, so  I've created work-arounds